# Issue writing to a file

Tags: c#, output

I was wondering why my code wont work, when I type it like this:

```
using (var off = File.CreateText("Apžiūra.txt"))
{ 
    for (int b = 0; b < TAExpired.Count; b++)
    {
        off.WriteLine(
            "Manufacturer: {0}, Model: {1}, Plate: {2}, Car Expiring: {3}/{4}", 
            TAExpired.Get(b).Manufacturer, 
            TAExpired.Get(b).Model, 
            TAExpired.Get(b).Plate, 
            TAExpired.Get(b).CarExpYear, 
            TAExpired.Get(b).CarExpMonth);
    }
}
```

What I mean is it should display info from three different cities in notepad, but it displays only one's. When I use Console.Writeline instead of off.WriteLine it works perfectly, what could be the case? For example, in console it would say: Los angeles, New york and Washington with city's info, but in notepad only Washington appears.
Edit: it might look a little untidy, but it pasted in like this, so sorry.

Comment: I just said citites as an example, because I have info from three different cities about cars. And I need it to display like this for e.g.: City's name and on a new line all of cars with their info.

Comment: OK, engaging psychic powers: You are repeatedly calling this entire block of code including the `File.CreateText("Apžiūra.txt")` part. When you use `File.CreateText`, the file is truncated and you lose what you already wrote to it. You should wrap all your `off.WriteLine` calls in a single `File.CreateText`.

Comment: Are you saying you're calling the above code multiple times for different cities? It will not append to the file, you will only see the latest run. I agree with @Blorgbeard

Comment: So I will see only the latest run of FOR because of the File.CreateText right? So I should change it to what to be exact? I'm quite new to c#, that's why I want to make it clear for future. I tried using `using (StreamWriter off = new StreamWriter("Apžiūra.txt"))` but it doesn't change.

Comment: Edit: I fixed the problem, I changed it from `File.CreateText` to `File.AppendText`, seems It worked only for one city since I kept overriding the file by accident, I needed to use AppendText, thank You everyone who replied!